# Coworkers insist on using asynchronous communication synchronously

Tags: communication, email

I work 100% remotely, as does the rest of my company. We use Microsoft Teams and email for everything. Some of my coworkers communicate with me by sending a single "Hi Iannaa" email or Teams message, and then they follow up 15 minutes later like "Let me know when you're free". Sometimes a little bit after this they'll CC either their or my manager and ask if I'm in the office today.

If I'm quick to see the message, I sometimes respond with "What's going on?" and they just ask if I'm free now. They never tell me what they want until they know that I'm "live" and we're several messages or emails in. This is becoming more and more common, and some people I work with are starting to sound really annoyed at me for not participating in their only-live communication style. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Related (but I'm not sure it's a duplicate exactly) [How to gently enforce "nohello" to a coworker?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/119137/26699)

Comment: Have you tried setting your "Status" in Teams to let people know when you are and are not available? You can also use your email client's auto-reply function to answer the "are you free" question. Sometimes a nudge in the right direction is all people need.

Comment: @ColleenV that assumes people actually check the status indicator/message. In my experience, most don't beyond looking at the color of the bubble (green, red, yellow)

Comment: @alroc Some people do, some people don't. Setting your availability does change the color of your bubble. In Outlook, people should see your auto-reply as they are typing their message (I'm not sure if that's a thing our IT guys have configured or if it comes out of the box that way). We have the technology, we should use it. If people don't look, it's easy to say: By the way, you can always check X to see if I'm free.

Comment: Microsoft Teams (like any other chat platform) *is* synchronous, though?

Comment: @nick012000 you might be mixing latency with synchronicity. While low latency is necessary for synchronous communication, it is not sufficient. Synchronous communication needs all the involved parties to be communicating at the same time for it to work (think phone call, ignoring voice mail), while chat programs don't need the recipient to be online and using the app for the sender to send a message in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Consistently let them know that it's more efficient for both of you if in the future they immediately open up with their question rather than waiting for you to reply.

It'll take a while but eventually, they'll understand your message, if you remain polite, positive, and professional.

Linking *and explaining* some online resource (like this one for example https://nohello.net/ ) *after* you reply to their queries, can facilitate the process.

Comment: First two paragraphs are spot on - unfortunately the third isn't, putting a "nohello" link in your chat profile comes off as extremely passive-aggressive IMO and that's the complete opposite of "polite, positive and professional"

Comment: @motosubatsu It depends on the context around the link. If it's alone in an empty text box you may have a point. If it's well described, it's much less of a problem (if it's a problem at all)

Comment: Respectfully disagree.. the message of "nohello" is a great one, but linking to it lieu of actually explaining to your colleagues yourself how you like to communicate is saying "go click this link before I'll deem you worthy to talk to me, I won't lower myself to explain it". If you want to convey that info in your profile (which isn't a great place since that's assuming people even go read your profile first) you just.. convey the information yourself in a polite, professional way.

Comment: @motosubatsu fair enough. I removed the mention of profiles and reworded the paragraph a little bit.

Comment: nice one - that's much better IMO

Comment: I wonder if, as a part of this answer, looping a manager in to both the need and the proposed response would help. The manager should have insights into both company culture and how the asker's time should be prioritized.

Comment: Sounds good, doesn't work. I'm trying it since two years. Some people don't care, some are new. Employee fluctuation makes this more effort than just dropping a line of "What's up?".

Answer (score 5):

You only need to give one response to these types of communications:

> Hello, how can I help you?

This lets them know that you are available and are willing to help them with their issue.  If they respond with something like "are you free" simply repeat the same question: "how can I help you?".  Usually, this is enough to make them understand that you are free and willing to help them and should eventually cut down on the needless back and forth communication prior to actually dealing with whatever issue is at hand.

Comment: I was searching for an other solution e.g. nohello links, but there is no workaround. This answer is the only one that works, just ask them what they want. I would just add, that I call people if they are responding with more than 3 messages.

Answer (score 2):

First, try responding to them politely to request use of an IM for conversation / meeting / discussion.

If that falls into deaf ears, next time onwards if there is no proper subject line and body in those emails, ignore them. If / when they copy your manager into the email (asking about your presence or availability), reply with something like

> *Hey , I'm available as usual. If you have something do discuss on priority, consider using the IM to drop me a ping / call me. While focusing on work, sometimes email responses are delayed, please do not treat email response as availability indicator. Thanks for understanding.*
>
> *So, how may I help you?*